# Align two TikZ trees next to each other and respecting each others bounding boxes

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm trying to align two TikZ nodes next to each other (second node is right of first node). I've achieved this, but the second node is floating inside the first nodes box, what I want to prevent.

[image: Bounding boxes]

```
\usepackage{tikz} % drawing
\usetikzlibrary{trees} % drawing nodes hierarchically
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % helps position elements

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {rectangle, draw = black, thick, anchor = west},
  company/.style = {fill = blue!40},
  department/.style = {fill = blue!30},
  person/.style = {fill = blue!20},
  grow via three points = {one child at (0.5,-0.7) and two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
]
  \node [company] (c1) {Company 1}
    child {node[department] (d1) {...}}
    child {node[department] (d2) {Department}
      child {node[person] (p1) {Person 1}}
      child {node[person] (p2) {Person 2}}
      child {node[person] (p3) {Person 3}}
    };

  \node [right=of c1] [company] {Company 2}
  child {node[department] (d3) {Derpartment very very long department name}
    child {node[person] (p4) {Person 4}}
    child {node[person] (p5) {Person 5}}
  };
      
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I make the second node respect the first nodes box?

Comment: Another solution is to use two tikzpicrures with `[baseline=(c1.base)]` and the as yet unnamed second node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image: a]

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz} % drawing
\usetikzlibrary{trees} % drawing nodes hierarchically
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % helps position elements

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style = {rectangle, draw = black, thick, anchor = west},
        company/.style = {fill = blue!40},
        department/.style = {fill = blue!30},
        person/.style = {fill = blue!20},
        grow via three points = {one child at (0.5,-1.2) and two children at (0.5,-1.0) and (0.5,-1.9)},% <<<<<<<<<<
        edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
        ]
        \node [company] (c1) {Company 1}
        child {node[department] (d1) {...}}
        child {node[department] (d2) {Department}
            child {node[person] (p1) {Person 1}}
            child {node[person] (p2) {Person 2}}
            child {node[person] (p3) {Person 3}}
        };
        
        \node [company]  (c2) at ([xshift=5cm]c1){Company 2}% changed <<<<<<<<<< 
        child {node[department, text width=5.5cm,text ragged] (d3) {Derpartment very very long  department name}
            child {node[person] (p4) {Person 4}}
            child {node[person] (p5) {Person 5}}
        };
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and you also helped me with the very long department name. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This uses a scope with a named local bounding box.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} % drawing
\usetikzlibrary{trees} % drawing nodes hierarchically
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % helps position elements

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {rectangle, draw = black, thick, anchor = west},
  company/.style = {fill = blue!40},
  department/.style = {fill = blue!30},
  person/.style = {fill = blue!20},
  grow via three points = {one child at (0.5,-1.2) and two children at (0.5,-1.0) and (0.5,-1.7)},
  edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=box]
  \node [company] (c1) {Company 1}
    child {node[department] (d1) {...}}
    child {node[department] (d2) {Department}
      child {node[person] (p1) {Person 1}}
      child {node[person] (p2) {Person 2}}
      child {node[person] (p3) {Person 3}}
    };
\end{scope}

  \node (c2) [right] at (c1 -| box.east) [company] {Company 2}
  child {node[department,align=left] (d3) {Derpartment very very long\\ department name}
    child {node[person] (p4) {Person 4}}
    child {node[person] (p5) {Person 5}}
  };
      
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```